# Serialization pattern for models and DTO's

Tags: c#, xml, json, serialization, asp.net-web-api

I have some Models which I want to make serializable to use them for a rest-service.

Currently, our implementation is very elaborate. The output can differ from ApiController to ApiController. I'm not able to clear or remove the Enumerable of the Model. This should be controlled by the DTO's.

I saw lots of comments that DTO's are outdated. However, I think the idea of decoupling between model and presentation is very good.

At the moment this would lead to lots of objects which I want to reduce.

I found only a few design pattern recommendations like memento, but not sure if this is correct. I also found an advice to use Mixins but not sure yet if it helps to solve my problem.

I'm sure there are lots of best practices which I don't see because I just search for the wrong terms.

Following only some pseudo-code to clarify what I mean.

```
public class PersonEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }

    public string Details { get; set; }

    public List<string> LotsOfSubInformation { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class PersonWithoutSubDtoXml
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Age")]
    public int Age { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Details")]
    public XmlCDataSection Details { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class PersonDtoXml
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Age")]
    public int Age { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Details")]
    public XmlCDataSection Details { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("LotsOfSubInformation")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Information")]
    public string[] LotsOfSubInformation { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class PersonDtoJson
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("age")]
    public int Age { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("details")]
    public string Details { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("lotsOfSubInformation")]
    public string[] LotsOfSubInformation { get; set; }

    public static PersonDtoJson Create(PersonEntity source)
    {
        return new PersonDtoJson
        {
            Age = source.Age,
            Details = source.Details,
            Name = source.Name,
            LotsOfSubInformation = source.LotsOfSubInformation.ToArray()
        };
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class PersonWithoutSubDtoJson
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("age")]
    public int Age { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("details")]
    public string Details { get; set; }

    public static PersonWithoutSubDtoJson Create(PersonEntity source)
    {
        return new PersonWithoutSubDtoJson
                                      {
                                          Age = source.Age,
                                          Details = source.Details,
                                          Name = source.Name
                                      };
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not see why you do not derive. And I do not see why you need different object for serialisation as Json and as XML. Please explain. Serialisation is a property of the class, not something that lets you make different classes. And DTOs are never outdated, this is not a concept sort of thing, just a way of grouping data. (besides you see the DTO as your model, which would be somehow wrong).

Comment: in this Pseudo-Code the XML-DTOs use a CDATA-Section. This is not readable by JSON?!? Further there is a stripped DTO for each type because of a simple list like an overview and a complete list like for a detail-page.